# Airflow plugin to preview local data files

Tags: flask, airflow, flask-admin

I use Airflow for my ETL pipelines and I use local pickle files for storing data (usually pandas DataFrames) in some temporary folder.  I'd like to navigate and preview these local data files directly from the Airflow UI using a [plugin](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/plugins.html).

Here is my first attempt, using the [`FileAdmin`](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_contrib_fileadmin/) class from `Flask-Admin`:

```
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from flask_admin.contrib.fileadmin import FileAdmin

DATA_PATH = '/tmp/somepath'
 
class DataFileAdmin(FileAdmin):
    # read only
    can_upload =  False
    can_delete =  False
    can_mkdir =  False
    can_delete_dirs =  False
    can_rename =  False

dfv = DataFileAdmin(DATA_PATH, '/static/', name='Data Explorer')

class AirflowTestPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "data_explorer"
    admin_views = [dfv]
```

Placing this into `plugins/data_explorer.py` produces a "Data Explorer" button in the Airflow UI (in the upper bar) allowing to browse the files inside the specified folder.  Good.

Now: **how can I specify the behavior when I click on a pickle file?** This means these files (pickled DataFrames) should be read by `pandas.read_pickle()` and then "printed" as a HTML table (or Plotly graph, or even better some interactive table allowing to sort and filter... suggestions welcome!). Thank you.